# Django Search bar feature not working?

Tags: python, django

In my base template I have this search bar. When I search for something it doesn't actually return anything. I'm not sure if the url is correct because I want it to work on every page.

In the base navbar this is the code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" target="_self">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label class="control-label" for="search-field">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></label>

        <input type="text/submit" value="{{request.GET.q}}" name="q" 
         class="form-control search-field"
         action={% url 'search_posts' %} 
         placeholder="Search Airline or Aircraft" id="search-field" />

    </div>
</form>
```

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', search_posts, name='search_posts'),
```

**Views.py**

```
def search_posts(request):
    aircraft = Aircraft.objects.all()
    airline = Airline.objects.all()

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        aircraft = aircraft.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=query) |
        Q(description__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    return render(request, 'search_post.html', {'aircraft': aircraft})
```

Is it possible to combine two models into a variable? I have `Aircraft` and `Airline`. Will this work?

```
queryset_list = Aircraft.objects.all() + Airline.objects.all()
```

**Views.py Updated**

```
def search_posts(request):
    aircraft = Aircraft.objects.all()
    airline = Airline.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("q")

    aircraft = aircraft.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=query) |
    Q(description__icontains=query)).distinct()

    airline = airline.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=query) |
    Q(description__icontains=query)).distinct()

    return render(request, 'search_post.html', {'aircraft': aircraft,'airline': airline })
```

**search_post.html**

```
<div class="team-boxed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row aircraft">
          {% for aircraft in aircraft %}
            <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
                <div class="box"><img src="{{ aircraft.image.url }}" />
                    <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ aircraft.get_absolute_url }}">{{ aircraft.name }}</a></h3>
                    <h4><em>Range: {{ aircraft.maximum_range }} NM</em></h4>
                    <h4><em> Passengers: {{ aircraft.passengers }}</em></h4>
                    <h4><em> Speed: {{ aircraft.cruising_speed }} Kt</em></h4>
               </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTML [`input`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) elements do not have an `action` attribute, remove `action={% url 'search_posts' %}` from `<input>` and place it inside the `<form>` like this:

```
<form action={% url 'search_posts' %} method="GET" ...>
```

Also remove the `type="text/submit"` from the input and replace it with just `text` (in order to present the user a text input box to write the query - thanks Alasdair for that - haven't seen that), like this:

```
<input type="text" ...>
```

so, the `form` should look like this:

```
<form method="GET" action={% url 'search_posts' %} class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="search-field">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></label>
        <input type="text" value="{{request.GET.q}}" name="q" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search Airline or Aircraft" id="search-field" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Concerning the other part of your question, in order to combine two (or more) `QuerySet`s (I can't imagine why you would want to do that), here it is:

```
qs = list(Aircraft.objects.all()) + list(Airline.objects.all())
```

Finally in your `search_post.html` do this:

```
{% if aircraft.exists %}
    <div class="team-boxed">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row aircraft">
                {% for aircraft in aircraft %}
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
                        <div class="box"><img src="{{ aircraft.image.url }}"></div>
                        <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ aircraft.get_absolute_url }}">{{ aircraft.name }}</a></h3>
                        <h4><em>Range: {{ aircraft.maximum_range }} NM</em></h4>
                        <h4><em> Passengers: {{ aircraft.passengers }}</em></h4>
                        <h4><em> Speed: {{ aircraft.cruising_speed }} Kt</em></h4>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if airline.exists %}
    <div class="team-boxed">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row airline">
                {% for airline in airline %}
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
                        <div class="box"><img src="{{ airline.image.url }}"></div>
                        <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ airline.get_absolute_url }}">{{ airline.name }}</a></h3>
                        <h4><em>Range: {{ airline.maximum_range }} NM</em></h4>
                        <h4><em> Passengers: {{ airline.passengers }}</em></h4>
                        <h4><em> Speed: {{ airline.cruising_speed }} Kt</em></h4>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I dont want a seperate submit button because it ruins the look for the navbar.

Comment: It's not a separate one. Just change the existing `input` to the one in my answer.

Comment: You want `type="text"` - if you use `type="submit"` then it will be a button and the user won't be able to change the search term. The user can still submit the form by pressing return after filling out the search box.

Comment: I want the user to be able to search both models. If I add another if statement will be okay?

Comment: Don't add an `if` clause. Just add another query to the other model, like this: `airlines = airline.filter(...).distinct()`.

Comment: @nik_m I've updated my code, so please have a look at the views updated and the html page. The problem I'm having is that the container for the airline is sligtly different to the aircraft. Do I add an if statement in the html to check whether the post is an aircraft or airline? Because the way it is now, the airline is not showing up because it's an aircraft container.

Comment: @nik_m You're a life saver!